# How to rewrite Ruby's `Array(x)` in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, clojure-contrib

In Ruby, there is [`Kernel#Array`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-Array) method, which acts like this:

```
Array([1, 2, 3]) #=> [1, 2, 3]
Array(1..5)      #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
Array(9000)      #=> [9000]
Array(nil)       #=> []
```

In other words, it converts nil to empty array, non-collections to singleton arrays, and kinds of collection-like objects (i.e. objects which respond to `#to_ary` or `#to_a`) to arrays.

I want to have something similar to this in Clojure:

```
(to-seq [1 2 3])     ;=> (1 2 3)
(to-seq (range 1 5)) ;=> (1 2 3 4)
(to-seq 9000)        ;=> (9000)
(to-seq nil)         ;=> nil; () is ok too
```

That's what I've got so far:

```
(defn to-seq [x] (if (seqable? x) (seq x) '(x)))
```

But I don't like it because:

1. The [`seqable?`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_contrib/clojure.contrib.core/seqable_q) function evaporated during [the explosion](http://dev.clojure.org/display/doc/Clojure+Contrib+Libraries) of monolithic clojure-contrib. I don't want to include huge ancient no-longer-supported library to my project just for one function.
2. I have a feeling that there must be a built-in function that is either in *clojure.core* or in *clojure.contrib.whatever*. Or that there's more idiomatic approach.

The exact output type of `to-seq` is not important. The main thing is that I'd like to use its output, say, in list comprehensions:

```
(for [person (to-seq person-or-people)] ...)
```

So if will be a vector - it's ok. If it will be a vector, a Java array, a list or nil depending on the input - that's fine too.

**==== UPD ====**

The *almost* final version:

```
(defn to-seq [x] (if (or (nil? x) (coll? x)) x [x]))
```

The final version:

<strike>`(defn to-seq ..blabla..)`</strike>

I don't need to-seq, it doesn't look attractive.

Comment: As a side note, `'(x)` evaluates to a singleton list containing the symbol `x`; you'll want to use `(list x)` or `[x]` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only need to iterate over the input and it is actually a container of some sort, you don't usually need to perform any special conversions. The two special cases which come to mind are handled by `enumeration-seq` and `iterator-seq`.

That being said, I believe there actually is no ready-made function in core for determining whether an object is a valid input to `seq`. The relevant code resides in `clojure.lang.RT`'s `seq` and `seqFrom` methods and basically tries several possibilities in turn; I believe `seqable?` checked the same possibilities -- you could do the same. Existing functions like `coll?`, `seq?`, `sequential?` all fail to catch at least some of the cases (notably arrays and strings); `coll?` probably comes closest, `sequential?` is notably used by `flatten` (which is therefore limited in its ability actually to flatten things).

Of course there's always the possibility of trying to apply `seq` and catching the exception (not that I'd recommend it):

```
(defn seq-at-all-costs [x]
  (try
    (seq x)
    (catch IllegalArgumentException e
      (list x))))   ; NB. '(x) wouldn't work, since it would
                    ; cause a literal symbol x to be returned,
                    ; as noted in my comment on the question
```

You could also do something like this to speed things up (hopefully -- I'd definitely benchmark):

```
(defprotocol IKnowHowToSeqYou
  (seq-knowledgeably [this]))

(defn seq! [x]
  (try
    (seq-knowledgeably x)
    (catch IllegalArgumentException e
      (try
        (seq x)
        (extend-type (class x)
          IKnowHowToSeqYou
          (seq-knowledgeably [this]
            (seq this)))
        (catch IllegalArgumentException e
          (extend-type (class x)
            IKnowHowToSeqYou
            (seq-knowledgeably [this]
              (list this)))))
      (seq-knowledgeably x))))
```

I have to say, though, that I hardly ever -- perhaps actually never -- feel the need for `seqable?`. The reason is probably that it's relatively unusual that I have completely no idea what types of objects I'll be dealing with at any given point, and in those rare cases I tend to go through cases / use protocols / use multimethods etc.

---

Here's the checklist used by `RT.seq` and `RT.seqFrom` as of now:

1. if input is already a seq (which to `RT.seq` means "an instance of `clojure.lang.ASeq`", not `ISeq`), it is returned unchanged;
2. if it's a lazy seq, it is forced and the result is returned;
3. otherwise if it implements `Seqable`, then it's asked to produce a seq of its contents;
4. if it happens to be `nil` (`null`), `nil` is returned;
5. if it's `Iterable`, an iterator seq is returned;
6. if it is an array, an array seq is returned;
7. if it is a `CharSequence`, a string seq is returned;
8. if it is a `java.util.Map`, a seq over its entry set is returned;
9. otherwise an exception is thrown.

Comment: _I have to say, though, that I hardly ever -- perhaps actually never -- feel the need for `seqable?`._ Yeah, the need for `seqable?` smells not very good for me too. I'll try to refactor the code so it's not necessary. In the meanwhile, I'm going to use `coll?` since it fits my needs at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

```
(map coll? [() [] #{} {} 1 "sandwich" :a nil])) 
;=> (true true true true false false false false)

(defn to-seq [x] (if (coll? x) (seq x) (list x)))
```

[`coll?`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/coll_q) any use?

See also: [`seq?`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/seq_q) or [`sequential?`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/sequential_q)

Comment: Yep, `coll?` is suitable. Thank you.